# how to use loop in foreach?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Currently I fetch all result from discount_master table (product id, discount). But instead of product id I want to display product_name which is in product_master table and they share same product_id. My concern is how can I add a loop that fetch product_name from product_master?

```
<?php
    foreach($discount as $k=>$v) {
?>
    <tr>
        <th contenteditable="false" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'product_id','<?php echo $discount[$k]["d_id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $discount[$k]["product_id"]; ?></th>
        <th contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'discount','<?php echo $discount[$k]["d_id"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $discount[$k]["discount"]; ?></th>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: You should use sql joins for that rather then a second loop.

Comment: You should be using a `JOIN` query to also return the `product_name`. Then in your loop use just `<?= $v["product_name"]; ?>`..

Comment: `SELECT * from discount_master where o_id='$o_id'` this is my sql query i am fetching all details using o_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try this one    

 $qry=mysqli_query($con' SELECT discount_master.product_id,discount_master.discount, product_master.product_name,product_master.product_id,FROM discount_master LEFT JOIN product_master ON discount_master.product_id= product_master.product_id'); 

        while ( $data=mysqli_fetch_array($qry)) {
            $product_id = $data['product_id'];
            $product_name=$data['product_name'];
            $product_discount=$data['product_discount'];
            echo $product_id." ".$product_name." ".$product_discount;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul Bro i use this query now everything is working.